# Series expansion of the power 1/4

Tags: analysis, inequality, power-series, binomial-coefficients

There exists an inequality that links the expression
$$\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^{k+j} (2\mu)^{k}\binom{1/4}{k+j-1}$$
where $\mu <1/2$ and $j\ge 2$ with the expression
$$\sum_{k\ge 0 }(-1)^k (2\mu)^k \binom{1/4}{k}=(1-2\mu)^{1/4}$$
?
I would like to have that the first expression is less than the second one.

Comment: When $j=1$ the first is the negative of the second.

Comment: Ok, something stronger? I needed the case $j>1$

Comment: So you want $-1 \le \mu < 1/2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=k+j-1$: For $j\gt 1$

$
\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^{k+j}(2\mu)^k\binom{1/4}{k+j-1}=\sum_{m\ge j-1}(-1)^{m+1}(2\mu)^{m-j+1}\binom{1/4}{m}=$

$-(2\mu)^{j-1}\bigg((1-2\mu)^{1/4}-\sum_{m=0}^{j-2}(-1)^m(2\mu)^m\binom{1/4}{m}\bigg)$

Comment: I made some minor changes to your answer for readability. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking something like: isolate in the sum $\sum_{k\ge 0}$ the part depending by $j$, that is writing the first expression as $\sum_{k\ge0 } (-1)^j C(j) (-1)^k (2\mu)^k \binom{1/4}{k}$ and then show that $C(j)<1$. Is this possible?

Comment: @GiovanniFebbraro It looks difficult because of the binomial term.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The bottom line came out too long, so I changed it a little.

Comment: If you could show the finite sum in the final expression is less than the infinite sum, you will have your inequality.